# Trying to get last item from JSON feed and update only if feed has changed

Tags: jquery, json

I have this JSON feed of a radio station's current playlist: http://cjzn.streamon.fm/metadata/recentevents/CJZN-48k.json

What I would like to do is display using jQuery the last item in the feed (which is the currently playing song) and then occasionally (every 3 minutes) check to see if the last item (or, the new currently playing song) has changed and update the page, but if it hasn't changed don't bother updating.

I am pretty lost when it comes to this. Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: If it's just a JSON file and you have no access to the data, or other server-side technology you have to poll it with each client. (The workarounds are simply not worth it).

Comment: Any reason in the world why you can't just always "update" after each request?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).
2. Add a random number to your URL to prevent server caching, like this: http://cjzn.streamon.fm/metadata/recentevents/CJZN-48k.json?rand=3
3. Use a javascript timer: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
4. On every request, save your last item and check if the previous item you saved is equal

Comment: Okay but how do I get the *last* item in the JSON request? I'm good about getting the first item using `items[0]`, but if the feed returns a different number of items every time, how do I target the last item only?